# Java Spring check in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I need to check how works spring web application.
I think to set breakpoints in constructors of all beans.
In this way I suppose can receive perception which bean created, order of creation,  links between beans. Is this way correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) which is a fork of Eclipse produced by SpringSource. I think you can also just add an STS plugin to a regular Eclipse install. It has a "spring explorer" view that lets you browse the bean config, even if they are wired via annotations.

Comment: Beware, that annotations support is **VERY** limited.